# How to check multiple lists indexes (making a game)?

Tags: python, indexing, console

I'm new at programming and I'm trying to make a four in a row game in console (Python). I was wondering how can I check when there is a four in line.

I'm using lists to make the board. For example:

```
def tablero(colum,filas):
tablero=[]    

for x in range(1,filas+1):
    tablero.append([" "]*colum)

for x in tablero:
    x.insert(0,"")
    x.insert(len(x), "")

for x in tablero:    
    print ("_|_".join(x))

return tablero

tablero(7,7)
```

Now, let's say that player one chooses column 1 of the board to add the ficha. My program has to check if there is something in the first row and so on to find out in which row the ficha goes. That's one thing I haven't realized how to do, yet.

Second thing is that after every player turn the program has to check if there is a 4 in a row and I haven't realized that. For example my board is:

```
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
```

After player one plays:

```
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_X_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
```

Now the program has to check if my X is part of a four in a row, which is very difficult to me.

If you can help me, I'll really appreciate it. Thanks.

PD: Sorry if my english is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of all the possible ways for 4 slots to line up; they are: left to right, top to bottom, top-left to bottom-right, and top-right to bottom-left.  So what you do is iterate through each slot in `table` and then check each of the possible ways for four similar symbols to be in a row.  It could go something like:

```
def checkForWin():
    for y in range(0, len(table)):
        for x in range(0, len(table[y])):
            if table[y][x] != " ":
                # left to right check
                if table[y][x] == table[y][x] and table[y][x + 1] == table[y][x] and table[y][x + 2] == table[y][x] and table[y][x + 3] == table[y][x]:
                    return table[y][x]

                # more checks
```

I hope this helps.
-=m0dem=-